# Testing thread safety

Tags: unit-testing, multithreading

Say you have a function `f` that is or contains a critical section.  How would you unit test that only one thread can run it at once, that it doesn't have race conditions, and that it doesn't cause a deadlock, etc...?

Comment: -1 "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an _entire book_ that answers your question, you’re asking too much." ([Programmers FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask "What kind of questions should I not ask here?"))

Comment: there does exist tools like [CHESS](http://chesstool.codeplex.com/) that "systematically enumerates the possible thread schedules to find hard-to-find concurrency errors, including assertion violations, deadlocks, data-races, and atomicity violations." However as @DeadMG points out, any tool that do this can only fail to find a defect, not actually ensure that there are no defects

Comment: @ConradFrix - I don't really agree that testing is about verification that something works.  I take a sort of scientific approach to in and so follow the philosophies of Karl Popper on the matter: testing is about trying to break code.  In other words, my code becomes sort of my working theory and my tests are my attempts to falsify that theory.  A theory that remains unfalsified is not proven to be correct, it's only proven not to be incorrect wrt the current understanding.  I simply _NEVER_ use tests as "proof" that my code is bug free.  That would be kind of silly I think.

Comment: @crazy eddie I don't disagree with you and I don't know what I said that led you to belive that I felt differently, but ok.

Answer (score 7):

You can't. Testing can only prove that you didn't find any bugs, not that none exist, and in the presence of multi-threaded code, I would say that it's almost pointless. You cannot test for how your function behaves when the OS changes it out or pauses execution or any of a thousand external events which can affect when the thread is scheduled and it's behaviour.

You need to, at least informally, prove the function correct.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do a "strong" test, but you can mitigate some risk by doing a "weak" test.

Parameterize `f` to take some additional code if passed in.  Then in the test, pass code for a thread counter, a sleep and an assertion that the thread counter never got above 1.  When running the test I would use 5-10 threads.  I would also restructure a function **without** a critical section and make sure the thread counter got above 1.  The idea would be to make sure the serialization was a result of the critical section only.

Answer (score 1):

Add sleeps around operations within `f` and add a parameter to let you control their length. You can then unit test as normal, but with different scheduling patterns.

Answer (score 0):

TDD is useless in multi-threaded scenarios. You don't test thread safety, you prove it, or it counter-proves you, painfully...